# Minecraft Docker Image: game storage persistence

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use [this Vanilla Minecraft docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/webhippie/minecraft-vanilla/) to run a Minecraft server for friends, but can't seem to get its data to live beyond the lifetime of the container itself.

I am running on an Ubuntu host, and on that host I have created `/opt/minecraft` where I'd like any outside-of-container persisted data to live.

To test my approaches I would:

- start the container (commands provided below with each approach I tried)
- join the server
- dig a circle around myself as an indicator that I've been there
- disconnect from the server
- stop the container `docker stop generated_name`
- start the container again using the same command as above
- join the server again
- is the circle I dug still there / has the world changed?

I have yet to find an approach that doesn't lose my data. Here's what I've tried:

## Approach 1: all in one

I tried just mounting `/opt/minecraft` as `/minecraft` in the container:

```
docker run -d -v /opt/minecraft:/minecraft -p 25565:25565 webhippie/minecraft-vanilla
```

## Approach 2: individual volumes

I noted in the Dockerfile that there are [3 volumes listed](https://github.com/dockhippie/minecraft-vanilla/blob/master/Dockerfile#L19):

```
VOLUME ["/minecraft/merge", "/minecraft/world", "/minecraft/logs"]
```

So after destroying and recreating an empty `/opt/minecraft` and creating the three folders to mount, I tried this instead:

```
docker run -d -v /opt/minecraft/world:/minecraft/world -v /opt/minecraft/merge:/minecraft/merge -v /opt/minecraft/logs:/minecraft/logs -p 25565:25565 webhippie/minecraft-vanilla
```

---

In both approaches 1 and 2 I can see that some files have been created in the folder(s) mounted as volumes (so I don't think it's a permissions issue), but it doesn't seem to be enough to keep my world from being created from scratch again after a container restart. What am I missing?

I'm also new to Minecraft. Maybe there's some nuance about the game that I'm missing, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach should be totally fine to keep the world, at least that's how I'm doing that.

Comment: Thanks for validating. I think it might have been that saving wasn't on, maybe? I did some playing with the `manage` tool and enabled saving and did an immediate save, and now it does seem to be working. Scheduled regular saves with cron and everything seems good now. Thanks!

Comment: All the manage commands are also available ingame, if you enable autosave you don't need any cronjob at all. You can see the rcon command at https://github.com/dockhippie/minecraft-vanilla/blob/master/rootfs/usr/libexec/manage-save-on#L8